# Cross system composer package installing

Tags: composer-php

I have a linux  web server with set of different users who have specific access to different virtual hosts.

All of these users belongs to one common group “www-data” ( apache ) and I want each of theses users be able to use the packages installed by composer. Sort of the same as the Debian packages installed via “apt-get” package manager...

So far I have tried installing composer the packages as super user but the executables becomes inaccessible for other users.
Linking the

```
.composer/vendor/bin/package-name
```

to

```
/usr/bin
```

or

```
/usr/local/bin
```

doesn't work so I am wondering if the composer is designed to redundantly install composer packages for each specific user? 
If not what is the confinguration of the composer.json to redirect the package installation to

```
/usr/bin
```

instead of  keeping them locked in

```
.composer/vendor/bin
```

?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make the installed packages usable by any system user we have to create a composer.json located in the add-on packages directory (/opt/composer) and run the “composer install” command from there.

Ex:

```
cat /opt/composer/composer.json 
{
    "require": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "phploc/phploc": "*",
        "pdepend/pdepend" : "2.1.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "*", 
        "nikic/php-parser" : "*", 
        "theseer/phpdox": "*", 
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "*" 
    },   
   "require-dev": {
        "phploc/phploc": "*",
        "phpmd/phpmd" : "@stable"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "/usr/local/bin"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as the "add-on packages directory" when it comes to Composer. You defined this directory to play this role, it is a local decision (i.e. this does not conform to any standard because this hasn't been standardised). Also note that your software cannot have mixed dependencies: Any package that contains a `composer.json` file will create a local installation of dependencies. There is no benefit for anyone to use a central installation of packages, because they cannot assume such thing exists on a server, and it likely does not contain the correct version.

Comment: This won't work because vendor directories permissions are 0750, meaning only the user and group owners of the vendor directories will be able to read and execute the binaries.

Comment: Hm, actually it might be a umask issue I'm facing with Ubuntu. I'll try with Debian (which has a different umask) and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Composer is proposing individual installation of packages per application. It is explicitly NOT designed to be like PEAR with a central installation of packages to be used, because this usually is a pain to update.

So when it comes to your users making use of their own virtual host, they should be able to put all of the files needed into their webspace independent of everyone else.

Now I was thinking about you providing the useful stuff like a centrally managed copy of Composer or other utilities, but I'd rather not because it's likely a bad idea.

Composer isn't an installer. It shouldn't be used as the tool grabbing all the files and put them onto the production machine. It's more like a developer tool to manage dependencies. Using Composer on your server means that people are using your server as a development environment. If this is true, they have the right to have Composer installed, but they should be able to do it on their own.

The other thing is with utilities like PHPUnit or Phing. While I think that some of them might be useful, the problem with a central installation is that it'll never be the right version. For example, if you'd provide PHPUnit, you can either go with the newest 4.6 and upset the users who still use the old 3.x, or provide that old 3.7 version and upset users who need the 4.x series. The same applies to Phing, to a lesser extent.

Comment: Taking in account that pear is dying and I prefere a central package management what would be the best alternative to composer?

Comment: Central package management is the problem, not PEAR. As an example, how would you solve the problem that one application requires "guzzle/guzzle" in version 3.7, and another application requires version 3.9? You cannot install both at the same location, so you'd install them in two locations, adding the burden to your users to somehow select the correct one. Don't try to force central package management upon your users. If they are smart (or simply follow install instructions from the manual), they won't even use these packages, because their usage of Composer will install individual copies.

Comment: The initial question is “cross system composer package installing”. If I want to install a specific package for a specific user I will proceed per user package installation and path variable overriding. It is counter productive redoing installation of the same elements for a system with a few hundred users.

Comment: If we are talking about "a few hundred users", it is very likely they all require individual versions of packages depending on which software they are using. And I also cannot feel it's counter productive, because managing the dependencies of a software is the task of the human who wants the software installed. If you provide centrally installed software, then this central installation will of course have only ONE location with it's dependencies. If this is not the case, your users will install their dependencies on their own when they install their software.

Answer (score 0):

So far, my solution has been to run a system-wide composer, installed to `/usr/local/bin/composer`, with a working-directory in `/usr/local/lib/composer/`. I then configure the `bin_dir` to `/usr/local/bin` to have composer automatically symlink the package binaries.

My problem, so far, is that composer creates the vendor files with restricted permissions for all users (640 and 750). My workaround is to `chmod` all I need.

It goes like this:

```
# install composer
sudo wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar --output-document=/usr/local/bin/composer

# setup composer home
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/composer
sudo touch /usr/local/lib/composer.json

# configure composer
sudo composer config bin-dir /usr/local/lib --working-dir=/usr/local/lib/composer

# install packages (drush, for example)
sudo composer require drush/drush:7.* --working-dir=/usr/local/lib/composer

# fix permissions
sudo find /usr/local/lib/composer -perm 640 -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /usr/local/lib/composer -perm 750 -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```